# Command is working, but also getting 'interaction failed' at the same time?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Title might be a little confusing so here's a screenshot of what's happening when I type a command:

[image]

It works, but then it fails at the same time. I get no errors from this interaction. Here's my code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("suggest")
    .setDescription("Send your suggestion to the specified channel")
    .addStringOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("suggestion")
        .setDescription("Your suggestion")
        .setRequired(true)
    ),
  async execute(interaction) {
    let suggestion = interaction.options.getString("suggestion");
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("#0099ff")
      .setTitle(`New suggestion by ${interaction.member.displayName}`)
      .setDescription(`${suggestion}`);
    await interaction.channel
      .send({
        embeds: [embed],
      })
      .then(function (interaction) {
        interaction.react(``).then(interaction.react(``));
      });
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deferring the reply. More info on it [here](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/replying-to-slash-commands.html#deferred-responses)

For example,

```js
const wait = require('util').promisify(setTimeout);

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    if (interaction.commandName === 'ping') {
        await interaction.deferReply();
        await wait(4000);
        await interaction.editReply('Pong!');
    }
});
```

Comment: unfortunately, deferReply just made it fail completely. Here's an imgur link to the screenshot: https://imgur.com/f1aDKBT

Comment: Hmm, can you send me the error?